# RCTRefreshControl may only be managed by a UITablewViewController

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the following ugly error while trying to implement a RefreshControl on a ScrollView in my react native application:

[image: refreshControl error]

Here's what I'm rendering:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this._onRefresh}></RefreshControl>}
      style={styles.scrollView}>
      {renderFeedItems()}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

Any ideas?

```
"react-native": "^0.21.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with an upgrade to react-native 0.29.0